# Displaying user website link in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is this fine or is there a different way?

```
 <a href="Http://<%=Html.Encode(Model.Website)%>"><%=Html.Encode(Model.Website??"")%></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fine to me, although you might want to check that the website doesn't already start with "http://" as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [custom HTML Helper](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-09-cs.aspx) to do it for you.